# converting a mysql update with join in stored procedure to sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an update statement that I'm stuck on that need conversion to sql server, can someone give me some direction?

Here is the statement:

```
UPDATE #Commission 
INNER JOIN (Select cl.UserId, SUM(cl.CommissionAmount) As CommTotal
            From CommissionLog As cl
            Where cl.CommissionPeriodId = @CommissionPeriodId
            Group By cl.UserId) As cl
    ON cl.UserId = c.Id
SET Commission = cl.CommTotal;
```

and the temp table layout is:

```
 CREATE TABLE #Commission(
            Id int,
            FirstName varchar(255),
            LastName varchar(255),
            JobTitle varchar(255),
            Commission decimal(18,4) default 0,
            Chargeback decimal(18,4) default 0
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UPDATE c
SET Commission = cl.CommTotal
FROM #Commission AS c
INNER JOIN (Select cl.UserId, SUM(cl.CommissionAmount) As CommTotal
            From CommissionLog As cl
            Where cl.CommissionPeriodId = @CommissionPeriodId
            Group By cl.UserId) As cl
    ON cl.UserId = c.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/30/sql-server-update-from-select-statement-using-join-in-update-statement-multiple-tables-in-update-statement/) to learn Update using joins in `SQL SERVER`.

```
UPDATE c
SET c.Commission = cl.CommTotal
FROM #Commission c
INNER JOIN (Select cl.UserId, SUM(cl.CommissionAmount) As CommTotal
            From CommissionLog As cl
            Where cl.CommissionPeriodId = @CommissionPeriodId
            Group By cl.UserId) As cl
    ON cl.UserId = c.Id;
```